# Play Framework DIST failing with ScalaDoc generation

Tags: playframework, jooq

I am using Play 2.5.1. I have included my build.sbt and errors. I am also using Jooq, where I have some code generated, and I am not sure if that is causing the issue(s) or not.

Using activator, I clean, compile, package, and then run dist. Dist is what is failing for me. Will this hold up deploying of my app?

Below are my errors.

```
[myproj] $ dist
[info] Wrote /home/me/git/myproj/target/scala-2.11/myproj_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Packaging /home/me/git/myproj/target/scala-2.11/myproj_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Main Scala API documentation to /home/me/git/myproj/target/scala-2.11/api...
[info] Packaging /home/me/git/myproj/target/scala-2.11/myproj_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT-web-assets.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[error] /home/me/git/myproj/app/jooq/JooqCodegenStrategy.java:8: not found: type Mode
[error]     public String getJavaClassName(Definition definition, Mode mode) {
[error]                                                           ^
model contains 352 documentable templates
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:doc) Scaladoc generation failed
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed Apr 22, 2016 5:10:47 PM
[myproj] $
```

Below is my build.sbt.

```
import sbt.Keys._
organization := "com.myproj"
name := "myproj"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

val appDependencies = Seq(
  cache,
  javaWs,
  javaJdbc,
  javaJpa,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.38",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq" % "3.7.3",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq-meta" % "3.7.3",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq-scala" % "3.7.3",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq-codegen" % "3.7.3",
  "be.objectify"  %% "deadbolt-java"     % "2.5.0",
  "com.feth" %% "play-authenticate" % "0.8.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "com.feth" %% "play-easymail" % "0.8.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.6.2",
  "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.2.0",
  "org.easytesting" % "fest-assert" % "1.4" % "test",
  "org.seleniumhq.selenium" % "selenium-java" % "2.52.0" % "test",
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.14",
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.14",
  "org.ocpsoft.prettytime" % "prettytime" % "4.0.0.Final"
)

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")

javacOptions ++= Seq("-Xlint:unchecked")
javacOptions ++= Seq("-Xlint:deprecation")
javacOptions ++= Seq("-Xdiags:verbose")

sources in (Compile,doc) := Seq.empty

unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "libs"

lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies
  )

includeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "main.less"
excludeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := new PatternFilter("""[_].*\.less""".r.pattern)

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The report is weird, but this does not looks like a scaladoc error, but a compilation error. Are you able to locally run the project? What happens if you run `sbt clean compile`?

Comment: I am using Activator to clean, compile, package, dist in terminal. Otherwise, I am running my project from Intellij, and the project runs fine (both from Intellij and from terminal using activator run). I will try to remove Jooq and see if I get the same errors.

Comment: I tried the exact same steps with my project that is similar but does not include Jooq, and it worked. I was able to run activator, then clean, compile, package, dist. No issues. I then ran those exact same commands with my current project, and dist worked this time. I am not sure why it worked this time but not the others. I will keep an eye on it. Thanks for your feedback.